# Why framer-motion does not animate array of items, like single items?

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I'm using `framer-motion` to animate a list.
I want items to slide from left, one by one.
Following the [docs](https://www.framer.com/docs/animation/), I can animate the items one by one, when they are single, but not when mapping through an array.

```js
const items = ["one", "two", "three"];

function App() {
  const list = {
    visible: {
      opacity: 1,
      transition: {
        when: "beforeChildren",
        staggerChildren: 0.3,
      },
    },
    hidden: {
      opacity: 0,
      transition: {
        when: "afterChildren",
      },
    },
  };

  const item = {
    visible: { opacity: 1, x: 0 },
    hidden: {
      opacity: 0,
      x: "-100vw",
    },
  };

  return (
    <motion.ul initial="hidden" animate="visible" variants={list}>

// This does not work as expected.
      {items.map((item, i) => (
        <motion.li variants={item}>{i}</motion.li>
      ))}
      
// This works fine! 

      <motion.li variants={item}>item</motion.li>
      <motion.li variants={item}>item</motion.li>
      <motion.li variants={item}>item</motion.li> 

    </motion.ul>
  );
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
What is the way of using `staggerChildren: 0.3,` in an array?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a way!
Credits to [Leigh](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u_95SPKE6vg)

```js
const items = ["one", "two", "three"];

function App() {
  const itemVariants = {
    initial: { x: "-100vw", opacity: 0 },
    animate: { x: 0, opacity: 1 },
  };

  return (
    <ul>
      {items.map((item, i) => (
        <motion.li
          variants={itemVariants}
          initial="initial"
          animate="animate"
          transition={{ duration: 0.3, delay: i * 0.8 }}>
          {i}
        </motion.li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```